# Regular expression with quantified part and negative lookahead

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I need check if a string contains the pattern: starts with "A" followed by zero or more spaces and then anything but not "B".

So, the following must match: `"A"`. `"AX"`, `"A   X"`, `"A   "`, `"A  XB"`

The following strings must not match: `"AB"`, `"A   B"`

My naive attempt was `A\s*(?!B)`, but it matches the undesirable `"A B"`.

Comment: Do you mean you need to just check if it matches? Like with `A(?!\s*B)`? Or are you extracting these substrings from longer strings? Please clarify. Maybe you need `(?>A\s*)(?!B)`? Also, it would help if you post the relevant C# code.

Comment: Updated the post. I am not capturing values, but need to check if there's a substring matching the pattern anywhere in the input.

Comment: Do you want to match `"A  "`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to get true or false, you may put the `\s*` into the lookahead:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, @"A(?!\s*B)")
```

It finds `A` that has no 0+ whitespaces followed with `B` after it.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=A%28%3F!%5Cs*B%29&i=A%0D%0AAX%0D%0AA%20%20%20X%0D%0AA%20%20%20%0D%0AA%20%20XB%0D%0A%0D%0AThe%20following%20strings%20must%20not%20match%3A%20%0D%0AAB%0D%0AA%20%20%20B).

In your pattern, `A\s*(?!B)`, the negative lookahead can be executed after any 0+ whitespaces, and once a whitespace not followed with `B` is found, a valid match is returned (that happens due to backtracking that is possible thanks to `\s*` quantified pattern).

If you need to actually match the `A` and the whitespace after it, but if these whitespaces are not followed with `B`, use the pattern from my comment.

```
(?>A\s*)(?!B)
```

This pattern matches:

- `(?>A\s*)` - an atomic group, matches `A`, then 0+ whitespaces *with no backtracking into the group pattern* allowed
- `(?!B)` - no `B` after the spaces, or the whole match is failed.

Comment: The atomic group works best so far. However, it doesn't work if "A" and "B" are the same string, e.g. `(?>A\s*)(?!A)` still matches `A   A`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `(?>A\s*)(?!A)` still matches `A A` because the pattern finds partial matches and thus matches the second `A` that is not followed with 0+ whitespaces and then `A`. Please precise what you are doing.

Comment: @Impworks I think you are trying to match a string that has no `A\s*B` pattern. Why not just use `!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"A\s*B")`? If there must be `A\s*`, combine it like `Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(?!.*A\s*B).*A")`

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Based on the comment below, use this pattern `A\s*B|(A)` and check against group #1

---

Use this pattern `A\s*+(?!B)\w*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EOwdpq/2)

```
#    A\s*+(?!B)\w*
A           # "A"
\s          # <whitespace character>
*+          # (zero or more)(possessive)
(?!         # Negative Look-Ahead
  B         # "B"
)           # End of Negative Look-Ahead
\w          # <ASCII letter, digit or underscore>
*           # (zero or more)(greedy)
```

or based on your attempt, use this `A\s*+(?!B)`

Comment: .NET Regex engine doesn't support possessive quantifiers though.

Answer (score 0):

The attempt doesn't work because it matches the `"A"` before the `" B"`, I would suggest attempting to take the negative approach, and writing `A\s*B` and use all non-matching lines. For example with grep `grep -v "A\\s*B"`.

If the A is needed and there are non-`A` lines you can search twice, `grep A | grep -v "A\\s*B"`.