# Excluding bad matches from unstructured date searches- R

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation

I have some highly unstructured date data which contains numerous errors. Currently my `regex` capture syntax is pretty great at getting all of the dates but it also grabs numbers that not dates. These numbers are typically followed by notation which should help predict if those numbers are some kind of number or a date.

```
uglydates = c(
  "05-01-2018 Worked on PP&E valve. Specimens are unusually active.",
  "55.2 psi containment pressure nominal.",
  "August 11, 2018 Personal Journal, I thought I would like being alone. I was wrong.",
  "34.1 PSI reported on containment unit 34. Loss of pressure, cause unknown.",
  "10 3/4 casing seems to have ruptured. Exterior has numerous punctures",
  "perhaps caused by a wild animal.",
  "1.06.19 Hearing chittering noises in the woods.",
  "Thursday, February 2, 2019 Returned to Bunker, Mr. Higglies is missing.",
  "Fri, February 3, 2019 through Sunday, February 5, 2019 Searched for Mr. Higglies",
  "Thursday, Feb 9, 19 What remained of Mr. Higglies found me...",
  "Bleeding profusely, returning to the silo.",
  "Friday, 2 27 19 - Have not been able to stop bleeding. Don't feel like eating.",
  "Leaving bunker in search of help.",
  "3 27 Can't walk any longer. Going to lie here for just a few minutes.")

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Function for adding parentheses around text
par <- function(x) paste0("(",x,")")

months <- month.name  %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
monab  <- month.abb  %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
days    <- (Sys.Date() + (0:6)) %>% format("%A") %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
dayab   <- (Sys.Date() + (0:6)) %>% format("%a") %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
num <- "([1-9]|[0-3][0-9]|201[6-9])" # 01-39, 1-9, 2016-2018

daydate <- paste(days, dayab, months, monab, num, sep= "|") %>% par

sep <-"[/\\-\\s/\\.,]*" # seperators

end <- "[\\s:\\-\\.\n$]" # Define possible end values

datematch  <- paste0("^(?i)(",daydate,sep,"){1,5}(",end,")")
#"^(?i)(((Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Monday|Tuesday)|(Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue)|(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|([1-9]|[0-3][0-9]|201[6-9]))[/\\-\\s/\\.,]*){1,5}([\\s:\\-\\.\n$])"

uglydates %>% str_extract(datematch)
# [1] "05-01-2018 "                 "55.2 "                       "August 11, 2018 "           
# [4] "34.1 "                       "10 3/4 "                     NA                           
# [7] "1.06.19 "                    "Thursday, February 2, 2019 " "Fri, February 3, 2019 "     
# [10] "Thursday, Feb 9, 19 "        NA                            "Friday, 2 27 19 - "         
# [13] NA                            "3 27 "
```

I have attempted to use negative look ahead `?!...` syntax but it doesn't seem to negate everything I need it to (the entire string capture).

```
exclude = "(PSI|casing)"
datematch  <- paste0("^(?i)((",daydate,sep,"){1,5}(",end,"))(?!", exclude,")")
# "^(?i)((((Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Monday|Tuesday)|(Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue)|(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|([1-9]|[0-3][0-9]|201[6-9]))[/\\-\\s/\\.,]*){1,5}([\\s:\\-\\.\n$]))(?!(PSI|casing))"

uglydates %>% str_extract(datematch)
# [1] "05-01-2018 "                 "55."                         "August 11, 2018 "           
# [4] "34."                         "10 "                         NA                           
# [7] "1.06.19 "                    "Thursday, February 2, 2019 " "Fri, February 3, 2019 "     
# [10] "Thursday, Feb 9, 19 "        NA                            "Friday, 2 27 19 - "         
# [13] NA                            "3 27 "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current negative lookaheads negate only the final matched optional group as seen in this dummy example, see also e.g. [Regular expression with optional part and negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463437/regular-expression-with-optional-part-and-negative-lookahead)

```r
str_extract("0-0-0 psi", "((0[-]?)+)(?!\\spsi)")
#> [1] "0-0-"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A simple solution is to replace:

```
exclude <- "(.*(PSI|casing))"
```

which negates the entire string capture if `PSI` or `casing` are found:

```r
uglydates = c(
    "05-01-2018 Worked on PP&E valve. Specimens are unusually active.",
    "55.2 psi containment pressure nominal.",
    "August 11, 2018 Personal Journal, I thought I would like being alone. I was wrong.",
    "34.1 PSI reported on containment unit 34. Loss of pressure, cause unknown.",
    "10 3/4 casing seems to have ruptured. Exterior has numerous punctures",
    "perhaps caused by a wild animal.",
    "1.06.19 Hearing chittering noises in the woods.",
    "Thursday, February 2, 2019 Returned to Bunker, Mr. Higglies is missing.",
    "Fri, February 3, 2019 through Sunday, February 5, 2019 Searched for Mr. Higglies",
    "Thursday, Feb 9, 19 What remained of Mr. Higglies found me...",
    "Bleeding profusely, returning to the silo.",
    "Friday, 2 27 19 - Have not been able to stop bleeding. Don't feel like eating.",
    "Leaving bunker in search of help.",
    "3 27 Can't walk any longer. Going to lie here for just a few minutes.")

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Function for adding parentheses around text
par <- function(x) paste0("(",x,")")

months <- month.name  %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
monab  <- month.abb  %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
days    <- (Sys.Date() + (0:6)) %>% format("%A") %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
dayab   <- (Sys.Date() + (0:6)) %>% format("%a") %>% paste(collapse= "|") %>% par
num <- "([1-9]|[0-3][0-9]|201[6-9])" # 01-39, 1-9, 2016-2018

daydate <- paste(days, dayab, months, monab, num, sep= "|") %>% par

sep <-"[/\\-\\s/\\.,]*" # seperators

end <- "[\\s:\\-\\.\n$]" # Define possible end values

exclude <- "(.*(PSI|casing))"
datematch  <- paste0("^(?i)((",daydate,sep,"){1,5}(",end,"))(?!", exclude,")")
# "^(?i)((((Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Monday|Tuesday)|(Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue)|(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|([1-9]|[0-3][0-9]|201[6-9]))[/\\-\\s/\\.,]*){1,5}([\\s:\\-\\.\n$]))(?!(.*(PSI|casing)))"

uglydates %>% str_extract(datematch)
#>  [1] "05-01-2018 "                 NA                           
#>  [3] "August 11, 2018 "            NA                           
#>  [5] NA                            NA                           
#>  [7] "1.06.19 "                    "Thursday, February 2, 2019 "
#>  [9] "Fri, February 3, 2019 "      "Thursday, Feb 9, 19 "       
#> [11] NA                            "Friday, 2 27 19 - "         
#> [13] NA                            "3 27 "
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I ended up going with `exclude <- "(.{0,10}(PSI|casing))"` since while not in the sample there are potentially dates that look like: "10-03-01 Recorded a PSI of 5".